# Java Swing : Extended ASCII characters not showing

Tags: java, swing, encoding, ascii

I'm trying to display ASCII characters in my JTextPanel, but it doesn't work for a few extended characters like ASCII 217, ASCII 180, and the up arrow that I didn't find in the ASCII table.

I read a file from the file system with ASCII characters, and let's say for the moment that my problem is to display the file content. For the characters above, a blank space is displayed instead.
I already tried all the available charsets from `Charset.availableCharsets()`, and several fonts.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("test");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 900, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

        JTextPane panel = new JTextPane();
        contentPane.add(panel);

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        if ( fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String s = null;
            if ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                panel.setText(s);
            }       
        }
    }
```

see we.tl/t-4hf9pgcsEZ (with https) to download a test file

here is the content of the file:

```
À¹ëÉÃN§T´jtkDÄ´†ê]":2q'6u$Q!44à!

  ®
```

When I past the content here in the 'edit question window' I see clearly the characters, but when I save my edits, many characters disapear... maybe a clue of the problem I'm facing

---

file converted in hexa with an online tool :

```
0xC0, 0xB9, 0xEB, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x04, 0x4E, 0xA7, 0x54, 0xB4, 0x6A, 0x74, 0x6B, 0x44, 0xC4, 0x18, 
0xB4, 0x17, 0x86, 0xEA, 0x5D, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x32, 0x17, 0x12, 0x13, 0x71, 0x27, 0x11, 0x36, 0x75, 
0x24, 0x51, 0x21, 0x34, 0x34, 0x10, 0x14, 0xE0, 0x21, 0x02, 0x0E, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 
0x0F, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAE,
```

Comment: What's "extended ASCII"?  Anyway, Java Strings are Unicode.  You read some 8859-1 bytes from the input, and converted them to Unicode, and then sent that Unicode string to the JTextPane.  From your description it doesn't seem like you're talking about actual 8859-1 characters, which as far as I recall has no up-arrow.  Therefore a (non-displayable) substitute character was probably used.

Comment: So your first task is to discover the actual encoding used in your file.  It's not ASCII. It's not 8859-1.  ["Extended ASCII"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) isn't an actual thing (there is no American standard), it's a loose name used for a slew of character sets identical to ASCII in the first 128 code points.  Do you have [MS_DOS code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), maybe?

Comment: Use `JTextPane.read(InputStream)` rather than that code seen above which would (AFAIU) only show the last line read. General tip: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the text file, or hot-link to one (put it on the net and load it directly from URL). BTW - `panel` is a confusing name for a `JTextPane`. Call it `textPane` or something more indicative of the underlying component.

Comment: thanks @another-dave, but how can I achieve that ? I already try with `Charset.availableCharsets()` and also with notepad++ to find the file encoding but no solution for the moment... :'(

Comment: dislayed characters are unicode characters, see [my screenshot](https://imgur.com/6vcffNf)

Comment: Can you give us a text file that you can't show its content?

Comment: The "manual" way is to look at a hex dump of the file and eyeball it against "all possible" code charts.  If you're on a Unix-like system, the ```file``` command might possibly identify the encoding.

Comment: Correlating bytes with characters would be useful.  One byte per character or more?  Fixed or variable number of bytes per character?

Comment: @George z. I've just add a link to download a test file, see we.tl/t-4hf9pgcsEZ with https

Comment: I will not visit this link you gave. Edit your question and add a sample of text in it AS TEXT.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. I put the text but dont know if it's readable...

Comment: @another-dave I put the file conveted in hexa. I'm on windows 7.

Comment: Looks like a random collection of bytes. Describe what it's supposed to look like. We're trying to guess how a message was encoded without knowing what the message is supposed to say.  How was this file created in the first place?  My guess would be some DOS codepage, which should be regarded as worthless in the 21st century.

Comment: yes indeed, the message has no meaning and is made of random characters. It's just an example i wrote to have as many different characters as possible. To tell you the whole story, my task is to re-write an application which can open file, translate in hexa, edit the hexa, and save it with this weird encoding. unfortunately I don't have the source code, but I know that this app is quite old...

Comment: A byte is just a byte.  It's you that has to say what the byte is supposed to mean.  E.g. if you say that 0xC0 is supposed to be a lower left corner for line drawing, then we can look for encodings where that is true.  if you say it's supposed to be capital letter A with grave accent then we can look for an entirely different encoding. "A byte with value c0" has no inherent definition.